# How to get my R version

Tags: r, version

To get the version of my R installation I use

```
R.Version()
```

and it produces a long output:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

# many more things
```

until I get the:

```
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)"
```

I also see the version as the first text from the R Console:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

# many other things
```

However, I wonder: is there any way to get the exact version without getting the rest of info? That is, is there any way to just get this:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
```

Comment: Perhaps `R.Version()$version.string`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From within R:

```
R.version.string
## [1] "R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)"
```

From the command-line you can grep it out:

```
> R --version| grep -Eo 'R version [0-9.]+ \([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\)';
## R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
```

Comment: You can get the version and much more with sessionInfo()

Comment: @lawyeR, I think the point is that they want *less* information :-)

Comment: @Ananda Mahto: Blush, you are right, and gracious about the nudge.  How about sessionInfo()[[1]]["version.string"]